# Vmware kernel module error

Tags: kernel, 16.04, vmware

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Kernel 4.6

I downloaded and installed Vmware workstation Pro 12. When I launch it I get this:
[image: Screenshot]

So I click install and then it fails:
[image: Screenshot]

This is the log:

```
2016-06-26T15:28:27.728+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Log for VMware Workstation pid=15490 version=12.1.1 build=build-3770994 option=Release
2016-06-26T15:28:27.728+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2016-06-26T15:28:27.728+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2016-06-26T15:28:27.728+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Host is Linux 4.6.0-040600-generic Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
2016-06-26T15:28:27.727+02:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2016-06-26T15:28:27.727+02:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2016-06-26T15:28:27.727+02:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2016-06-26T15:28:27.727+02:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2016-06-26T15:28:27.727+02:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.
2016-06-26T15:28:27.727+02:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2016-06-26T15:28:27.727+02:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2016-06-26T15:28:27.808+02:00| vthread-4| W115: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-15490.log
2016-06-26T15:28:27.820+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2016-06-26T15:28:27.820+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Created new pathsHash.
2016-06-26T15:28:27.820+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.6.0-040600-generic to "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include".
2016-06-26T15:28:27.820+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:27.820+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-06-26T15:28:27.820+02:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-06-26T15:28:27.820+02:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-06-26T15:28:27.827+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:27.827+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.6.0-040600-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-06-26T15:28:28.091+02:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/Module.symvers
2016-06-26T15:28:28.091+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.128+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 20001 symbol versions
2016-06-26T15:28:28.128+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.128+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.128+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.128+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.128+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.128+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.128+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.130+02:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.131+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.134+02:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.134+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.138+02:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.138+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.141+02:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.141+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.144+02:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.170+02:00| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2016-06-26T15:28:28.170+02:00| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2016-06-26T15:28:28.262+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.262+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.6.0-040600-generic to "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.262+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.262+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-06-26T15:28:28.262+02:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.262+02:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-06-26T15:28:28.272+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.272+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.6.0-040600-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-06-26T15:28:28.536+02:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/Module.symvers
2016-06-26T15:28:28.536+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.572+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 20001 symbol versions
2016-06-26T15:28:28.572+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include
2016-06-26T15:28:28.572+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include
2016-06-26T15:28:28.572+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.572+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-06-26T15:28:28.572+02:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.572+02:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-06-26T15:28:28.587+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.587+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.6.0-040600-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-06-26T15:28:28.589+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2016-06-26T15:28:28.594+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.3.1".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.594+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.595+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.600+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.3.1".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.600+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.603+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.603+02:00| vthread-4| I125: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.603+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.603+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.603+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-06-26T15:28:28.603+02:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.603+02:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-06-26T15:28:28.615+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.615+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.6.0-040600-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-06-26T15:28:28.617+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.617+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.617+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-06-26T15:28:28.617+02:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.617+02:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-06-26T15:28:28.629+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.629+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.6.0-040600-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-06-26T15:28:28.629+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.631+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.631+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.6.0-040600-generic to "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.631+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.631+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-06-26T15:28:28.631+02:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.631+02:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-06-26T15:28:28.642+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.642+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.6.0-040600-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-06-26T15:28:28.909+02:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/Module.symvers
2016-06-26T15:28:28.909+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.944+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 20001 symbol versions
2016-06-26T15:28:28.944+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.948+02:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-06-26T15:28:28.948+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2016-06-26T15:28:28.951+02:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-06-26T15:28:29.502+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2016-06-26T15:28:29.502+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2016-06-26T15:28:29.584+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2016-06-26T15:28:29.584+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j2 -C /tmp/modconfig-Stup0f/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2016-06-26T15:28:37.570+02:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2016-06-26T15:28:37.573+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2016-06-26T15:28:37.573+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2016-06-26T15:28:37.680+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2016-06-26T15:28:37.680+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j2 -C /tmp/modconfig-Stup0f/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2016-06-26T15:28:41.743+02:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
2016-06-26T15:29:58.319+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2016-06-26T15:29:58.319+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:29:58.319+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-06-26T15:29:58.319+02:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-06-26T15:29:58.319+02:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-06-26T15:29:58.335+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:29:58.335+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.6.0-040600-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-06-26T15:29:58.335+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2016-06-26T15:29:58.337+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2016-06-26T15:29:58.337+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.6.0-040600-generic to "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include".
2016-06-26T15:29:58.337+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:29:58.337+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-06-26T15:29:58.337+02:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-06-26T15:29:58.337+02:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-06-26T15:29:58.351+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:29:58.351+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.6.0-040600-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-06-26T15:29:58.630+02:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/Module.symvers
2016-06-26T15:29:58.630+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2016-06-26T15:29:58.669+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 20001 symbol versions
2016-06-26T15:29:58.669+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2016-06-26T15:29:58.672+02:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-06-26T15:29:58.672+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2016-06-26T15:29:58.676+02:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-06-26T15:29:59.092+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2016-06-26T15:29:59.092+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2016-06-26T15:29:59.105+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2016-06-26T15:29:59.105+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j2 -C /tmp/modconfig-f45QYh/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2016-06-26T15:30:00.937+02:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2016-06-26T15:30:00.940+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2016-06-26T15:30:00.940+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2016-06-26T15:30:00.950+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2016-06-26T15:30:00.950+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j2 -C /tmp/modconfig-f45QYh/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2016-06-26T15:30:03.381+02:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
2016-06-26T15:36:59.831+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2016-06-26T15:36:59.832+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:36:59.832+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-06-26T15:36:59.832+02:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-06-26T15:36:59.832+02:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-06-26T15:37:00.554+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:37:00.554+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.6.0-040600-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-06-26T15:37:00.554+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2016-06-26T15:37:00.556+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2016-06-26T15:37:00.556+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.6.0-040600-generic to "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include".
2016-06-26T15:37:00.556+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:37:00.556+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-06-26T15:37:00.556+02:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-06-26T15:37:00.556+02:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-06-26T15:37:00.570+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.6.0-040600-generic".
2016-06-26T15:37:00.570+02:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.6.0-040600-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-06-26T15:37:00.850+02:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/Module.symvers
2016-06-26T15:37:00.850+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2016-06-26T15:37:00.949+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 20001 symbol versions
2016-06-26T15:37:00.950+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2016-06-26T15:37:00.987+02:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-06-26T15:37:00.987+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2016-06-26T15:37:00.994+02:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-06-26T15:37:02.048+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2016-06-26T15:37:02.049+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2016-06-26T15:37:02.162+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2016-06-26T15:37:02.162+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j2 -C /tmp/modconfig-66YKCV/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2016-06-26T15:37:12.281+02:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2016-06-26T15:37:12.287+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2016-06-26T15:37:12.288+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2016-06-26T15:37:12.425+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2016-06-26T15:37:12.425+02:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j2 -C /tmp/modconfig-66YKCV/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2016-06-26T15:37:17.421+02:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Comment: have you got any solution  ? i am  trying  to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably because you have not installed the build environment, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

You also have to install the linux headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

If you are using a different kernel version than the kernel distribution  version, install the headers with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is still relevant with Ubuntu 18.04 and Vmware Workstation 15.0
(I just fresh installed both and it gave me the same error and this fixed it again)