# VMware kernel module update error in ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-53-generic

Tags: 16.04, apt, kernel, compiling, vmware

[image: this message is coming]

i followed  [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791611/vmware-kernel-module-error) for fixing this issue.

this below info took from the vmware-14167.log file

```
2016-12-06T17:39:36.437+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2016-12-06T17:39:36.438+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2016-12-06T17:39:36.438+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.4.0-53-generic to "/lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/build/include".
2016-12-06T17:39:36.438+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.4.0-53-generic".
2016-12-06T17:39:36.438+05:30| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-12-06T17:39:36.443+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.4.0-53-generic".
2016-12-06T17:39:36.443+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.4.0-53-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-12-06T17:39:36.575+05:30| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/build/Module.symvers
2016-12-06T17:39:36.575+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2016-12-06T17:39:36.594+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Read 18819 symbol versions
2016-12-06T17:39:36.594+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2016-12-06T17:39:36.596+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-12-06T17:39:37.242+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2016-12-06T17:39:37.242+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2016-12-06T17:39:37.249+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2016-12-06T17:39:37.249+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-A9Qpes/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2016-12-06T17:39:38.829+05:30| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
```